# Can username/passwords be intercepted on an App using public wifi?

Tags: wifi, man-in-the-middle

I use the ADVFN finance app for stock prices every morning on the public wifi on my train to work. This requires me to login with my username and password on the app(which are saved).

Do apps provide an extra layer of protection against potential hackers or could this data be intercepted?

Comment: Ask the developers of the app. Do they use cert pinning, and do they use TLS at all?

Answer (score 3):

Depends on the app. Some perform certificate checks, ensuring that you're connecting to a specific server with a specific secure method using a verified certificate, in which case, you're probably safe. Others simply make a HTTP call or don't bother verifying that the https certificate is legit, in which case, you're worse off than a website using HTTPS.

No general case, I'm afraid.

Comment: This is the right answer.  Said another way: assume "no" unless you're sure otherwise.